# A question about maximal subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory, subfactors

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H_1,\ldots, H_n$ a set of maximal subgroups of $G$. Let $\delta_{H_i}$ be delta functions with support on $H_i$, and let $A$ be the commutative algebra generated by $\delta_{H_i}$.

Question: is dimension of $A$ greater or equal to $n$?

Motivation: In 1961 G.E.Wall conjectured that the number of maximal subgroups in a finite group $G$ is less than the order of $G$.  A positive answer to the above question will imply Wall's conjecture. In fact it will even imply a relative version of Wall's conjecture: the number of maximal subgroups in $G$ which contain a subgroup $H$ is bounded by the number of double cosets in $G$, see [arXiv:1006.5947](http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.5947) for more discussions and motivations from subfactors.

The question seems to be combinatorial in nature: the basis of $A$ is simply the list of subsets of $G$ obtained by cutting with $H_i$'s. for $n =2,3$ one can check directly, and one may try induction on $n$. Any references on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Wall's conjecture is now known to be false : see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/104759/6451) and the answers there.

Comment: But still open up to conjugacy classes thanks to the answer of Nick Gill.